jQuery click function not working on AJAX request
I have this button which I want to get the value when clicked. If the code for this button is written directly in HTML, the function triggers. But when I generate the button using AJAX, it displays but the click function do not trigger.
This is my jQuery script:
  $('button').click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
    console.log(fired_button);
    });

I got this line of codes here: Get value of the clicked button
This what I have tried:
If I write this code directly to HTML:
<button type ='button' class ='btn btn-primary' value='5'>Delete<i class='bi bi-x-circle'></i></button>

The function triggers and it alerts the value '5'
But when the button is generated using AJAX request for a table, it do not trigger. Here is my code in the php file:
 $output .= "
 
            <tr>
            <td style='width:18%;'><button type ='button' value='$row[GIDh]'> class ='btn btn-primary'>Delete<i class='bi bi-x-circle'></i></button>
            <input type='text' hidden name='GIDname[]' value= '$row[GIDh]'>" . $row["GIDh"] .  "</td>;

This td is attached to a table. And it successfully generates the button, but the click function do not trigger. The line of code for the button is exactly the same, only the values are different.
I tried replacing the value of value='$row[GIDh]'> to value='5'> and it still do not trigger.
What might be cause of the problem?
I'm using the latest version of jQuery: 3.7.1.
Thanks in advanced.

Give the button a class of delete. Then do $('table tbody').on('click','.delete', function() { const val = this.value; /* do something with value */ this.closest('tr').remove() });

Thank you so much. I've added class button to delete like  $('participants_table tbody').on('click', 'button', function(){ /*...code */ }); And it worked well.
